# .NET LINQ foreach DATETIME cannot convert String to DateTime exception

Tags: .net, linq, exception, datetime, format

I have SQL data table that containes a DATE or DATETIME field

a LINQ statement show here just to get the basic idea

```
var testLinq = from t in DBDataContext.Certificates select t;

    foreach (var t in testLinq)
    {
     ....
    }
```

Left out the code in {..} for briefness.
BUT whenever 'foreach' tries to use t I get this exception

> "Input string was not in a correct
>   format." When converting a string to
>   DateTime, parse the string to take the
>   date before putting each variable into
>   the DateTime Object

How can I do this when its handled by Linq inside the foreach loop?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a little more code. How are you referencing the DateTime property?

Comment: Thanks, this exception occurs even if you dont even try and reference the property. It seems to throw when the foreach loop builds.
Ive tried using SQL Date & DateTime fields, and remembering to refreach my DataContext in Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make it like this

```
var testLinq = (from t in DBDataContext.Certificates select t).ToList();

foreach (var t in testLinq)
{
 ....
}
```

and convert your string to to datetime like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("yourString")
```

if its not working,

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year,month,day);
```

and get your year,month,day values with Convert.ToInt32(yourString.SubString(0,4)) etc